# Unity tutorial "Publish your first mobile runner game" runs under the editor. A build for Windows executes, but appears to ignore in-game mouse events

Tags: unity-game-engine

Tutorial: [link](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/publish-your-first-mobile-runner-game/?tab=overview&uv=2021.3).

Unity Editor 2021.3.28f1

Build target Windows intel-64 bit

I tried, without success:

1. Changing build target to 32 bit.
2. Changing project setting for 'Input System
   Package' to process events in each of the three options.

... and a handful of other suggestions related to old versus new methods for handling input.

Each time, the game runs fine in the editor, but it ignores the mouse during game play.  Of note, the mouse works for the introductory menu selections, but not during game play.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reviewing

Assets\Runner\Scripts\InputManager.cs

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
            m_InputPosition = Mouse.current.position.ReadValue();
            
            if (Mouse.current.leftButton.isPressed)
            {
                if (!m_HasInput)
                {
                    m_PreviousInputPosition = m_InputPosition;
                }
                m_HasInput = true;
            }
            else
            {
                m_HasInput = false;
            }
#else
            if (Touch.activeTouches.Count > 0)
            {
                m_InputPosition = Touch.activeTouches[0].screenPosition;

                if (!m_HasInput)
                {
                    m_PreviousInputPosition = m_InputPosition;
                }
                
                m_HasInput = true;
            }
            else
            {
                m_HasInput = false;
            }
#endif
```

It's clear that a preprocessor directive explicitly handles input differently in the editor environment.

Simply changing:

#if UNITY_EDITOR

to

#if true

... results in the the built executable working as expected under Windows.

FWIW, similar issues with losing mouse funcionality after build got me off on the wrong track for some time.  For example:

- [Mouse clicks aren't recognized when I build Unity game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31576843/mouse-clicks-arent-recognized-when-i-build-unity-game)
- [Mouse not working on Standalone build - New Input System](https://forum.unity.com/threads/mouse-not-working-on-standalone-build-new-input-system.1068932/)

As the very first tutorial on the Unity website, I wonder if others have had similar trouble.  Hope this helps.

Comment: in general you should probably not even rely on the target platform at all ... rather configure your input actions accordingly so they work for both mouse and touch input whatever is currently recognized as the primary pointer device

Comment: Sure.  derHugo, that seems about right.  I got thrown since this is a Unity tutorial.  The first one recommended for new developers, actually.  Cost me more time than I care to admit.